# How can I use Invoke-SqlCmd with variables to output the SQL command only or some similar method?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell, tools, automation

I have a big `*.sql` file that I run with `Invoke-Sqlcmd` and variables to do some tasks, and when I have an issue, it's a pain to debug because of the variables and I want to do logging of the SQL script about to be run.

Is there a reasonably native way to produce the final `SQL` about to be executed with variable substitution without actually running?

Here's a sample I run to restore a *.bak to various environments for example:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $sqlFile -QueryTimeout 0 -ServerInstance 'SQLServer' -Database 'Master' -Variable @("DatabaseBAK=$TransactDB", "Database=$TargetDatabase") -Verbose
```

SQL File:

```
USE [master]

print 'Killing connections to database $(Database)'
DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = '';

SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), session_id) + ';'
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE database_id  = db_id('$(Database)') 
 and session_id <> @@SPID
EXEC(@kill);
GO
USE [master]

print '[Info] RESTORE DATABASE [$(Database)]'
print '[Info] FROM DISK = N''$(DatabaseBAK)'''
print 'Starting restore-------------------->'
RESTORE DATABASE [$(Database)]
FROM DISK = N'$(DatabaseBAK)'
WITH FILE = 1
    ,NOUNLOAD
    ,REPLACE
    ,STATS = 5
GO
print '<--------------------End restore'
```

I would like to somehow just output the above with variable substitution the way Invoke-SqlCmd does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a clever way with `set quoted_identifier off`

[image]

**PowerShell**

```
$sqlFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TestOutput.sql"
$begin = 'set quoted_identifier off print "'
$end = '" set quoted_identifier on'

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $sqlFile -QueryTimeout 0 -ServerInstance 'Server' -Database 'Database' -Variable @("begin=$begin", "end=$end") -Verbose

$begin = '--Begin'
$end = '--End'

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $sqlFile -QueryTimeout 0 -ServerInstance 'Server' -Database 'Database' -Variable @("begin=$begin", "end=$end") -Verbose
```

**TSQL**

```
/*
$(begin) is either
    set quoted_identifier off print "
    or
    --Begin
*/

$(begin)
select SALESID from SALESTABLE where SALESID = 'SO-000003'
select SALESID from SALESTABLE where SALESID = 'SO-000004'
$(end)

/*
$(end) is either
    " set quoted_identifier on
    or
    --End
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, just use [**dbatools - restore-dbadatabase**](https://dbatools.io/functions/restore-dbadatabase/)

it has [extensive coverage of all the scenarios that you might ever need](https://dbatools.io/snowball/).

Note: dbatools also has a better version of invoke-sqlcmd --> [invoke-sqlcmd2](https://dbatools.io/functions/invoke-sqlcmd2/) with a `-ParseGO` to parse scripts with `GO` batch seperators and is more optimized version.

Comment: I'll check it out. The script is just an example though. I have some more complex ones that are doing a bunch of different things in automated code build processes for different environments.

Comment: dbatools module will not output those `PRINT` statements...just an FYI. You have to handle that type of output differently in PS when you use something outside of `Invole-Sqlcmd`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think invoke-sqlcmd can do thi.  Regular sqlcmd.exe has the -e parameter to output the batches, although it will not output the "GO"
.  EG

```
sqlcmd -e -i restore.sql -v database="foo" databaseBak="bk" > Restore.final.sql
```

You can put SET NOEXEC ON at the top, or just point it at an dummy instance to generate the script.

Or something like:

```
sqlcmd -e -Q "set noexec on;`n:r restore.sql" -v database="foo" databaseBak="bk"
```

Comment: What does the `'n:r` do?

Comment: I figured out a clever way you may find interesting - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/208540/16830